# Admob reset app locale to system default

Tags: android, admob

I set a local in my launcher activity, after a second or two the locale settings resets to the device's system locale settings.

After several hours of digging, I found the culprit, google admob.
While initilizing it's webview it rewrites the `Configuration` which creates a mess, with layouts, strings, and so on.

Anything I can do here?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was caused by using the deprecated `updateConfiguration` on API's newer than 17, the following code solves the issue (within activity), and sets a persisting locale settings.

```
public void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    Resources resources = base.getResources();
    Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        base = base.createConfigurationContext(config);
    }
    else {
        config.locale = locale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    super.attachBaseContext(base);
}
```