# android - admob reset Locale to default values

Tags: android, admob

In my app I set locale this way:

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

}
```

I call this method in Activity. All work fine until I put admob banner after that all resources change to default.

I found similar issue here [Admob reset app locale to system default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42795943/admob-reset-app-locale-to-system-default) but that solution didn't help me. What should I do to solve the problem ?

One solution that I have found is to set all resources in code depends on selected locale but it's too long for me and not convenient if you have more than two language.

Or if someone has a multi-language app with admob banner, please give me an example how do you implement localization.

Comment: Have you found the solution @athene ?

Answer (score 0):

helps for me:

```
 @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
               // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            setPref();
           }
```

setPref() is method for set locale