# Locale configuration issue after Load Admob ad

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

My Android Application is Multilanguage. When the user changing app Language, the app saves it in SharedPreferences to make changes permanent (set locale when the app opens).

The way I change language:

```
public static void changeInterfaceLanguage(Activity activity, @Language String lang) {
    Resources res = activity.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    Locale currentLocale = getCurrentLocale(activity);
    final Locale newLocale = new Locale(lang);
    if (!currentLocale.equals(newLocale)) {
      SettingsPrefsEdit.putString(activity, SettingCons.INTERFACE_LANGUAGE, lang);
      conf.setLocale(newLocale);
      res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
      activity.recreate();
    }
```

The way I restore Locale when the app opens:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String lang = SettingsPrefsGet.getString(activity, SettingCons.INTERFACE_LANGUAGE,
        SettingCons.LANG_ENGLISH);
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    activity.getResources()
        .updateConfiguration(config, activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    ...
}
```

Also, Admob Native Ads is implemented in this App.

The problem is this:
After destroying app and reopen it, exactly when my code calls any method from Admob library, the app language (Locale) is changing to English, and after that, every new screen of the app is in English.

Some of the methods that cause this problem:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this)
```

```
AdLoader.Builder adLoader = ...
adLoader.build().loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Useful notes:

- SharedPreferences doesn't get change when this problem occurs.
- There is only one Activity in the app. All pages are implemented as Fragment (50+ pages)
- After changing app language, everything is fine until *app getting destroyed*
- I'm using Firebase version of Admob:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.6.0'
```

What I've tried:

- When I disable all calls to Admob methods, the problem disappears.
- I moved *locale update* code block to MainApplication. But the problem exists yet.
- I re-implemented Language change operation with this library, but didn't resolve:
  https://github.com/YarikSOffice/lingver

Comment: Does same thing happen for every local? Can you try setting up locale with one of supported languagues https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9727?hl=en

Comment: also see if logs are giving any error?

Comment: also try solution provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42795943/admob-reset-app-locale-to-system-default

Comment: @AmodGokhale I tried the French Language. But didn't resolve. Also, didn't see any error

Comment: @AmodGokhale The solution provided in the link you gave WORKED. I'm testing for any potential bug. Thanks man.